# Link goes to "www.example.com/www.example.com/blog" instead of "www.example.com/blog "

Tags: url, hyperlink, redirect

On my website when people click on a link, instead of going from `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/blog`, they are redirected to `www.example.com/www.example.com/blog`.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you using IIS?

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens if you link to `www.example.com/blog` instead of `https://www.example.com/blog`.

If you are on `https://www.example.com/`:

- The `href` value `www.example.com/blog` will be interpreted as relative URL:

  ```html
  <a href="www.example.com/blog">Blog</a>
  ```

  → It links to `https://www.example.com/www.example.com/blog`
- The `href` value `https://www.example.com/blog` will be interpreted as absolute URL:

  ```html
  <a href="https://www.example.com/blog">Blog</a>
  ```

  → It links to `https://www.example.com/blog`